# Bokeh run time error, models must be owned by a single document

Tags: bokeh, pandas-bokeh

when trying to enter two datasource this error popped up.
RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document, StringFormatter(id='1266', ...) is already in a doc

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fields': x ,
    'C_Info': values
})

src_1 = ColumnDataSource(df_2)

cols = [
    TableColumn(field='Fields', title='Portfolio'),
    TableColumn(field='C_Info', title='CapInfo')
]

myTable = DataTable(source=src_1, columns=cols)

src_3 = ColumnDataSource(df2)

cols_1 = [
    TableColumn(field='variable', title='Earnings Component'),
    TableColumn(field='values', title='Amount'),
    TableColumn(field='PercentageTotalEarning', title='Percentage Total Earning'),
]

myTable2 = DataTable(source=src_3, columns=cols_1)

show(column(myTable,myTable2))
```

Comment: Are you using a Jupyter Notebook? This looks like an error which comes when you try to show a Bokeh Model twice. Did you run different cells with `show()`?

Comment: yes used show multiple times in the doc and it occurs only in jupyter notebook?

Comment: I know this from notebooks and can't say anything about scritps. Guess there this problem doesn't exist because the saving space is cleared immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when using `bokeh.plotting.save` and `bokeh.plotting.show` in the same cell of a python notebook.

**Solution**

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.io
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from IPython.display import IFrame
```

Now create your figure as usual, calling `bokeh.plotting.figure()`:

```
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(your figure as usual with plot_width and plot_height)
```

Now save your figure but don't show it using bokeh:

```
bokeh.plotting.save(p, filename="your path/name.html")
```

Now show your figure using `IFrame`:

```
IFrame(src='your path/name.html', width=1000, height=500)
```

Please note, width and height in `IFrame` should be set slightly larger than your figure dimension that you have set in `plot_width` and `plot_height`

Now you have both the saving and the displaying in the same cell.